# Exchange Web Services, Create All Day Appt in another Time Zone

Tags: web-services, soap, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Exchange and Time Zones are going to be the death of me.

My Exchange Server is located in EST (UTC -5). Version of Exchange is 2007 SP1. User is located in Paris France (UTC +2). If I try to create an appointment as an All Day Event, it will always span 2 days. Here is the request:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
        <ns2:MailboxCulture xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
            >en-US</ns2:MailboxCulture>
        <ns2:RequestServerVersion
            xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
            Version="Exchange2007_SP1"/>
        <ns2:TimeZoneContext xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
            <ns2:TimeZoneDefinition Id="Romance Standard Time"/>
        </ns2:TimeZoneContext>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <CreateItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
            xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
            SendMeetingInvitations="SendToAllAndSaveCopy">
            <SavedItemFolderId>
                <ns2:DistinguishedFolderId Id="calendar"/>
            </SavedItemFolderId>
            <Items>
                <ns2:CalendarItem>
                    <ns2:Subject>Test TZ</ns2:Subject>
                    <ns2:Body BodyType="Text"/>
                    <ns2:Start>2011-10-28T09:00:00Z</ns2:Start>
                    <ns2:End>2011-10-28T17:00:00Z</ns2:End>
                    <ns2:IsAllDayEvent>true</ns2:IsAllDayEvent>
                    <ns2:Location>Somewhere</ns2:Location>
                </ns2:CalendarItem>
            </Items>
        </CreateItem>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

NOTE: I have the Time Zone on my computer set to "(UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris", although the computer is physically located in EST.

This is what Outlook displays, spanning 2 days.
[image: What Outlook displays]

If I retrieve the newly created calendar item from Exchange, it shows the following start and end date/times:

```
<t:Start>2011-10-28T00:00:00Z</t:Start>
<t:End>2011-10-29T00:00:00Z</t:End>
<t:IsAllDayEvent>true</t:IsAllDayEvent>
```

([Entire response can be found here](https://gist.github.com/1322262))

I've tried various combinations of the start and end dates, but no matter what I do, I always get it spanning 2 days. If I run the same thing (without the tz context header) in EST, it will only span a single day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, answering my own question here. Looks like the key is setting the meeting time zone.

```
<ns2:MeetingTimeZone>
    <ns2:BaseOffset>-P0Y0M0DT2H0M0S</ns2:BaseOffset>
</ns2:MeetingTimeZone>
```

Since this was UTC +2, and the duration values must be positive, put the '-' on the "P". Since the TZ is "UTC +2", you subtract 2 to get UTC (hence then negative in the offset). If this was EST (UTC -5), then the BaseOffset would be P0Y0M0DT5H0M0S.

Hope this helps someone.

Full request looks like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
        <ns2:MailboxCulture xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
            >en-US</ns2:MailboxCulture>
        <ns2:RequestServerVersion
            xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
            Version="Exchange2007_SP1"/>
        <ns2:TimeZoneContext xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
            <ns2:TimeZoneDefinition Id="Romance Standard Time"/>
        </ns2:TimeZoneContext>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <CreateItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
            xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
            SendMeetingInvitations="SendToAllAndSaveCopy">
            <SavedItemFolderId>
                <ns2:DistinguishedFolderId Id="calendar"/>
            </SavedItemFolderId>
            <Items>
                <ns2:CalendarItem>
                    <ns2:Subject>Test TZ</ns2:Subject>
                    <ns2:Body BodyType="Text"/>
                    <ns2:Start>2011-10-27T22:00:00Z</ns2:Start>
                    <ns2:End>2011-10-28T22:00:00Z</ns2:End>
                    <ns2:IsAllDayEvent>true</ns2:IsAllDayEvent>
                    <ns2:Location>Somewhere</ns2:Location>
                    <ns2:MeetingTimeZone>
                        <ns2:BaseOffset>-P0Y0M0DT2H0M0S</ns2:BaseOffset>
                    </ns2:MeetingTimeZone>
                </ns2:CalendarItem>
            </Items>
        </CreateItem>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Saw a similar case where using the Java EWS client I had to change the SendInvitationsMode http://stackoverflow.com/a/20864321/448641